# How can I simplify my SQL schema such that I have less tables but retain referential integrity?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Given the below SQL Server schema, how can I combine the `CarWindow` and `HouseWindow` tables into one table?

I would like to keep the foreign key constraint to Car if it is a car window, and to House if it is a house window.

I cannot combine the `Car` and `House` tables into one table because they are modelling different entities.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CarWindow
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS HouseWindow
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Car
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS House

CREATE TABLE Car 
(
    Id int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    CarColumn varchar(200)
)

CREATE TABLE House 
(
    Id int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    HouseColumn_CompletelyDifferent int
)

CREATE TABLE CarWindow 
(
    IdCar int,
    IsBroken bit,
    CONSTRAINT fk_CarWindow_Car FOREIGN KEY (IdCar) REFERENCES Car(Id)
)

CREATE TABLE HouseWindow 
(
    IdHouse int,
    IsBroken bit,
    CONSTRAINT fk_HouseWindow_House FOREIGN KEY (IdHouse) REFERENCES House(Id)
)
```

Comment: *Why* do you want fewer tables?  What problem does it solve?

Comment: The tables that maintain IsBroken could be System Versioned tables

Comment: Looks like "IsBroken" is a property of House and Car. why do you have separate table for it? if Car and House are representing an instance of House and Car entity, "IsBroken" should be a column on those tables not separate tables.

Comment: Good point @iamdave. I suppose I was trying to stick to DNRY. But, I'm curious about any solution.

Comment: DRY principles get a bit wooly around SQL databases.  The desire to abstract common functionality can sometimes cause *significant* performance degradation.  Only optimise where you need to and after testing the impact.  As your Car Windows and House Windows are different entities, personally I would leave them in seperate tables.  You may, for example, want to add a `Double Glazed` flag at some point in the future to your `HouseWindow` records, which wouldn't make sense for a Car

Comment: thanks for your comment iamdave. One doubt I have for my situation, is that ```CarWindow``` and ```HouseWindow``` will always contain the same information in my program's world. I want to abstract the same functionality, but apply it to different entities. For example, there may be a ```Spaceship``` entity sometime in future, in which case I would need to add another table, ```SpaceshipWindow```, with the same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

A house presumably has multiple windows, some of which may be broken and some not. Same with a car. So I'm assuming, even though you haven't included it, that HouseWindow actually ought to have a primary key column called Id. Multiple HouseWindows will therefore have multiple Ids - but may share the same IdHouse.

And similarly for the cars and car windows case.

Implement a new table called ItemOfProperty. An item of property can be a car or a house.

```
CREATE TABLE ItemOfProperty
(
    Id integer IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    ItemType char(1) NOT NULL,
    ItemOfPropertyColumn varchar(200) ,
    CONSTRAINT itemofproperty_id_itemtype_key UNIQUE (Id, ItemType),
    CONSTRAINT itemofproperty_itemtype_check CHECK (ItemType in ('H', 'C'))
)
```

Car should have an ItemType attribute which is defaulted to 'C' (for Car), and should have a foreign key to ItemOfProperty:

```
CREATE TABLE Car
(
    Id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    ItemType char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'C',
    CarColumn varchar(200) ,
    CONSTRAINT car_id_itemtype_fkey FOREIGN KEY (Id, ItemType) REFERENCES ItemOfProperty (Id, ItemType) ,
    CONSTRAINT car_itemtype_check CHECK (ItemType = 'C')
)
```

Similarly for House:

```
CREATE TABLE House
(
    Id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    ItemType char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'H',
    HouseColumn_CompletelyDifferent integer,
    CONSTRAINT house_id_itemtype_fkey FOREIGN KEY (Id, ItemType) REFERENCES ItemOfProperty (Id, ItemType),
    CONSTRAINT house_itemtype_check CHECK (ItemType = 'H')
)
```

(Always insert an ItemOfProperty row prior to inserting its corresponding Car row or House row.)

Now, in the same way we've invented a thing called ItemOfProperty which can encompass cars and houses, we can also introduce a table called GenericWindow (which is what you've asked for) which encompasses car windows and house windows.

CarWindow and HouseWindow can reference GenericWindow in much the same way Car and House reference ItemOfProperty. And GenericWindow can reference ItemOfProperty. Because ItemType is used throughout, there is never any danger of a car window belonging to a generic window of the "house" type, nor of a house window belonging to a generic window of the "car" type.

Now you're free to add whatever non-car-specific / non-house-specific window attributes to GenericWindow, while keeping the car-window-specific attributes in CarWindow and the house-window-specific attributes in HouseWindow (*EDIT* - *or ditch the CarWindow and HouseWindow tables entirely if you feel that generic window attributes are all you ever need*).

Of course this type of approach could be extended beyond cars and houses, and beyond car windows and house windows. You'd need more tables, and more ItemTypes. But tables ItemOfProperty and GenericWindow would remain at the heart of the design.

Comment: Hi Nabav. Thank you for  your detailed answer. If I understand you correctly, your solution is to combine ```House``` and ```Car``` into one table, ```ItemOfProperty```. I can't do this in my program, and am looking for a solution that keeps the tables separate.

Comment: Hi Typeset, in my solution the `House` and `Car` tables would remain separate tables; but at the same time there would also be an overarching table called `ItemOfProperty`. As you want to introduce a generic window table (called `GenericWindow` in my design), the introduction of a generic `ItemOfProperty` table is an equally sensible move - and it allows your generic window to reference a generic item of property using a single foreign key constraint, while also (because of the presence of an item-type within the constraint) ensuring that a car window can never reference a house, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation Nabav. It is a good solution. However, in my case, I want to reduce the number of tables, and not add complexity.